# KDB function (1#) / projection

Tags: kdb

Reading this page http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#64-projection

```
    (1#) each 1001 1002 1004 1003
```

1001
1002
1004
1003
        each[1#] 1001 1002 1004 1003
1001
1002
1004
1003

what does 1# mean? I understand concept of projection, but what is 1#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` in this context means take, you take `1` of `each` element in the RHS argument. The result of take is a list as well, so in this case you get a list where each sublist is of length 1.

```
q) (1#) each 1001 1002 1004 1003
1001
1002
1004
1003
```

Answer (score 2):

This is also a projection. "#" is a dyadic funcion called as "take" which returns a list.

Reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#take

Ex:

```
     q> #[2;(1 2 3 4)]
```

Output:

1  2

Short Form: 2# (1 2 3 4)

We can project it by fixing first argument like:

```
     q> f:#[2;] 

     q>  f 1 2 3 4
```

output:  1 2

In your case , fixed argument is 1.

```
    q>f:#[1;]
```

and it is applied on each element of a list using "each"

```
    q>(f each 1001 1002 1004 1003) ~ (1#) each 1001 1002 1004 1003
```

output:  1b

It will convert  each element to a list which is equivalent to calling enlist on each element:

```
     q> (enlist  each 1001 1002 1004 1003) ~ (1#) each 1001 1002 1004 1003
```

Output :  1b